# lsort -unique -command for objects

Tags: sorting, tcl, rectangles, itcl

I have a list of rectangles, and, I need to report an error if there are overlapping ones.
So, I've decided to use `lsort -command` to sort my list and, then, compare new and old lists' lengths. If they're not equal, then, there are overlapping rectangles.

Here is the piece of code that does the work:

```
package require Itcl

    ::itcl::class Region {

        public method print { name } {
            puts "$name: $x1_ $y1_ $x2_ $y2_"
        }

        public method X1     { } { return $x1_ }
        public method Y1     { } { return $y1_ }
        public method X2     { } { return $x2_ }
        public method Y2     { } { return $y2_ }

        # The x1 coordinate of the region
        public variable x1_ ""

        # The y1 coordinate of the region
        public variable y1_ ""

        # The x2 coordinate of the region
        public variable x2_ ""

        # The y2 coordinate of the region
        public variable y2_ ""

    }

    # two regions will be equal <=> when they overlap each other
    proc compareRegs { region1 region2 } {
        return [ expr {[$region1 X2] <= [$region2 X1] || [$region1 Y2] <= [$region2 Y1] } ]
    }

    # reg1 and reg2 don't overlap
    Region reg1
    reg1 configure -x1_ 5.5 -y1_ 5.5014 -x2_ 6.5 -y2_ 5.7014

    Region reg2
    reg2 configure -x1_ 3.567 -y1_ 5.5014 -x2_ 3.767 -y2_ 5.7014

    # reg2 = reg3
    Region reg3
    reg3 configure -x1_ 3.567 -y1_ 5.5014 -x2_ 3.767 -y2_ 5.7014


    # create a usual list
    set myList { reg1 reg2 reg3 }

    # sort the list
    set mySortedList [lsort -unique -command compareRegs $myList]

    puts "start mySortedList"
    foreach reg $mySortedList {
        $reg print "reg"
    }
    puts "end mySortedList"
    # mySortedList = {reg2}

    if { [llength $mySortedList] != [llength $myList] } {
        puts "ERROR: Regions must not overlap"
    }

    # let's see what's going on
    # reg2 < reg1 is true
    puts "result of reg1 < reg2: [compareRegs reg1 reg2]"
    puts "result of reg2 < reg1: [compareRegs reg2 reg1]"
    # reg2 = reg3 is true
    puts "result of reg2 < reg3: [compareRegs reg2 reg3]"
    puts "result of reg3 < reg2: [compareRegs reg3 reg2]"
    # i.e, in sorted list we should have {reg2 reg1}
```

Seems `lsort -unique -command` is not working correctly or I'm doing something wrong.
How can I fix this? Or maybe there are better solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your comparison function. Comparison functions need to return *three* possible values: -1 (or in fact any integer less than zero) if the first value is larger, 0 if the values are equal, and 1 (really an integer greater than zero) if the second value is larger. But the `expr` operators you are using (`<=` and `||`) give boolean results, i.e., produce just 0 or 1 as values. That's just not going to work.

We need a different approach to the comparisons:

```
proc compareRegs { region1 region2 } {
    # Compare the X values by subtracting them from each other
    set cmp [expr {[$region2 X1] - [$region1 X2]}]
    if {$cmp != 0.0} {
        # Convert to an integer (-1 or 1)
        return [expr {$cmp < 0.0 ? -1 : 1}]
    }
    # Compare the Y values by subtracting them from each other
    set cmp [expr {[$region2 Y1] - [$region1 Y2]}]
    if {$cmp != 0.0} {
        # Convert to an integer (-1 or 1)
        return [expr {$cmp < 0.0 ? -1 : 1}]
    }
    # Both equal; return an integer zero
    return 0
}
```

Yes, this code is a bit long. Should work though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is really helpful. Just a correction in proc body (see edit in your answer).